# Modificadores TypeScript

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Hola tengo problemas al poner private o protected en TypeScript ¿A que se debera? estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje pero no entiendo por que me arroja ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna configuracion u opcion que haya omitido? las dependencias que estoy usando en Node.js son las siguientes

```
"dependencies": {
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"typescript": "^4.9.4"
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

probá haciendo esto:

```
(()=>{
  
  class User{

    constructor(
      protected name: string,
      public email: string,
      public age: number
    ){}

    get fullName(){
        return this.name
    }

    set fullName(anotherName: string){
        this.name = anotherName
    }      
  }

  const user = new User("Rodrigo", "Rodrick@gmail.com", 24)

})()
```

Lo que estoy haciendo acá es asignar las propiedades del nombre, email, y edad dentro del constructor, algo que se suele hacer para que sea mas legible el codigo, despues invoco un get y un set, el get sirve para acceder a cualquier propiedad de un objeto, y el set sirve para cambiar cualquier propiedad de un objeto, supuse que es lo que querias hacer. Y al inicio puse `"(()=>{" y lo terminé con "})()"`, eso es una funcion anonima autoinvocada, es una tecnica que se usa para que cuando tenes muchos archivos .ts, éstos no choquen entre sí. si no que esten separados por esta funcion